# C# Pass a javascript to a Master Page Body?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem, I am new to to C#, and at the company I work I need to pass the Google Ads Tracking Javascript but per the document it needs to be placed within the `<body> </body>` tags so that it works. But I do not see a way to put it in the body. i see header but not a body

```
masterPageBooks.Page.Header.Controls.Add(
  new LiteralControl(myGoogleAds.ToString()));
```

How can I do the same but to a body?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're NOT using 3 different versions of C#...

Comment: actually we are, the answer for any of them will help us. Thank you

Comment: what does `myGoogleAds.ToString()` return, a `<script>` tag, or an actual HTML body element, like a `<div>`?

Comment: I changed the version specific C# tags to the generic C# tag, as the question is not specific to any of the versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a content placeholder in the master page where you want the ads:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="GoogleAdsContent" runat="server" />
```

In each content page you put the ads in the corresponding content tag:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="GoogleAdsContent" runat="server">
<%= myGoogleAds %>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the page.

```
masterPageBooks.Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myGoogleAds.ToString()));
```

Comment: Oh really and It will put it in the Body?

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of options.

1. If the API is common to ALL pages, just embed the JavaScript in the master page
2. As a variation of #1, put the code in a .js file and link in the tags in the master page
3. Create a content area and include
4. Create a literal control and include in the page controls collection

I am certain there are other means of accomplishing this. Which do you choose of the above? Depends on whether you have this on EVERY page (#1,#2) or just some (#3,#4). It also depends on whether you like to work in tags (#3) or declarative "programming" or in code (#4).

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the literal control in your master page ASPX precisely where you want it, and then set the text of the literal control in Master.OnLoad.